# How to assign id to an element in CKEditor custom plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have created a custom plug-in in the CKEditor. Inside the plug-in there is a textbox to which I want to assign the ID. Reason for assigning an ID is that I want to show or hide this textbox on click of button.

Even if I am assigning an ID like other attributes of the element. In source code (I used inspect element), CKEditor is assigning some random ID (e.g cke_121_textInput) to this field.

This random ID cannot be known while writing the code.

Code goes like this: (CKEditor Dialogue JS)

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'testPluginDialog', function( editor ) {
...
elements: [
{
type: 'text',
id: 'txtCustomerName',
label: 'Customer Name',
commit : function( data )   {
data.txtCustomerName= this.getValue();
}
}...
...
```